# Short story identification: Man poisons wife with mushrooms and a large fungus appears for revenge

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Written in the form of a diary - a man (professor / mycologist ) poisons wife by substituting poisonous mushrooms for edible ones in her meal. He buries her a short distance from the house and a large mushroom / fungus grows in that place, which gradually poisons the ground all around it and digests any organic matter in contact with it. The circle eventually expands to include the man's house, in which he is trapped.

Comment: This was a short story in a sci-fi / fantasy collection, which I had as a second-hand book in the middle/late 1970s, if that helps...?